# Flutter Dialog not respecting width of it's child

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am having a simple  dialog box with `CircularProgressIndicator` as child. 
Dialog is not respecting width of any child.

[image: this is the screenshot]

 It was working fine a week ago, I have made no changes to this code, I just upgraded flutter version and this happened. I even tried downgrading my flutter version but it neither fixes this issue.
 Here's my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: DialogApp()));

class DialogApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DialogAppState createState() => _DialogAppState();
}
class _DialogAppState extends State<DialogApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Test"),
          onPressed: () {
            _showDialog();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  Future<Null> _showDialog() async {
    await showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return DialogWidget();
        });
  }
}
class DialogWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DialogWidgetState createState() => _DialogWidgetState();
}
class _DialogWidgetState extends State<DialogWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0)),
      child: AnimatedContainer(
        height: 60.0,
        width: 60.0,
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
        curve: Curves.ease,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.black)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Dialog has defined  `constraints: const BoxConstraints(minWidth: 280.0),` - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/dialog.dart

Comment: Thanks, that helped :) Changed the Dialog file.

Comment: Instead of changing the src file, I would recommend creating your own by copying the source & importing the file. else future flutter update will overwrite it.

Comment: @anmol.majhail yeah actually i changed it before upgrading too and then forgot about change

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, just wrap the `CircularProgressIndicator` so it takes the width and height wrap content.

```
child: Wrap(
          alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            CircularProgressIndicator(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.black)),

          ],

        ),
```

Comment: Yeah that fixes the issue with `CircularProgressIndicator` but what if i want to change `Dialog`width?

Comment: Yes you can change it

Comment: But my issue is that i want to change `Dialog`'s width to make it Square. I want it to be 60x60 but width is having no effect when i change it.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**  You just want to wrap your circulerProgressIndicator into the Center widget

```
Center(
   child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.black)),
   ),
),
```

**Option 2**
If you want display transparent processDialog then you add this method and call it whenever you require

```
void showLoadingDialog(BuildContext _context) async {
await showDialog(
    context: _context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return SimpleDialog(
        elevation: 0.0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        children: <Widget>[
          Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor:
                  AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(ColorUtils.primaryColor),
            ),
          )
        ],
      );
    });
}
```

[image]